# Can cache files be used in distributing capacity? (use Bitmap compress)

Tags: android, firebase, bitmap

By Android policy, instead of directly accessing the file path, we want to find the file in the cache file using the cache and fileprovider, reduce the size of the file, and send it to the server.

Do you by any chance know the correct way to compress the cache file? Is there any better way? The database used is Google Firebase Storage.

Oh, the reason I use the cache file is to refer to the photo file taken by cameraX.

this is my code.

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
fun compressImageWithFilePath(context: Context, filePath: String?, targetMB: Int) {
    var image : Bitmap
    var exifInterface : ExifInterface? = null
    val fileOutputStream : FileOutputStream
    val file : File

    var externalFile = File(context.externalCacheDir.toString())
    var selectedFile : File? = null
    var files = externalFile.listFiles()

    for (i in files.indices) {
        ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, "filePath : ${filePath},${i} : ${files[i].name}")
        if (filePath != null) {
            if(filePath.contains(files[i].name!!)) {
                ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, "일치")
                selectedFile = files[i]
            }
        }
    }

     if(selectedFile != null) {
        ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, selectedFile.path)
        //var file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "kr.gowoonwoori.oniontime.fileprovider", selectedFile!!)
         exifInterface = ExifInterface(selectedFile.absolutePath)
         image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedFile.absolutePath)
         file = selectedFile
         fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(selectedFile.path)

    } else {
         exifInterface = ExifInterface(filePath!!)
         image = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath)
         file = File(filePath)
         fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(filePath)
    }

    val exifOrientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(
        ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL
    )

    val exifDegree = exifOrientationToDegrees(exifOrientation)
    image = rotate(image, exifDegree)

    try {

        val length = file.length()
        val fileSizeInKB = length / 1024.0
        val fileSizeInMB = fileSizeInKB / 1024.0
        var quality = 100
        if (fileSizeInMB > targetMB) {
            quality = (targetMB / fileSizeInMB * 100).toInt()
        }

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, fileOutputStream)
        fileOutputStream.close()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
}



val uploadTask: UploadTask = when (type) {

            CloudStorageFileType.FILE -> {
                //storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(File(filePath)))

                    var externalFile = File(context.externalCacheDir.toString())
                    var selectedFile : File? = null
                    var files = externalFile.listFiles()

                    for (i in files.indices) {
                        ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, "filePath : ${filePath},${i} : ${files[i].name}")
                        if (filePath != null) {
                            if(filePath.contains(files[i].name!!)) {
                                ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, "일치")
                                selectedFile = files[i]
                            }
                        }
                    }

                if(selectedFile != null) {
                    var file = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "kr.gowoonwoori.oniontime.fileprovider", selectedFile!!)
                    ILog.iLogDebug(TAG, file.path)
                    storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(File(selectedFile.path)))
                } else {
                    storageReference.putFile(Uri.fromFile(File(filePath)))
                }
            }
```

Comment: Pretty unclear about which file you are talking or what would be a file in a cache file. Where is this about?

Comment: @blackapps  Sorry. I am not used to English. 
The photos taken with cameraX are saved as cache files inside externalCacheDir.  We want to reduce the photo files stored in this cache memory and send them to the server. Is it possibly impossible? 
The size of the photo file!

Comment: Of course you can scale down the resolution of an image file. Or make its compress quality less. All to make a smaller file size. Or save as .webp instead of .jpg. 30% less bytes.

Comment: @blackapps It's been a while since I developed Android, so I'm inexperienced. Does reducing the resolution work in cameraX? Or is it reduced in the cache file?

Comment: Reducing the resolution has nothing to do with cameraX. We were talking about reducing the resolution of a bitmap or a file.

Comment: @blackapps 
Oh, I'm sorry I didn't understand you well. For now, I'll do what you advised me to do. If there's no progress, I'll come back with a question. Thank you very much for your kindness!

Comment: @blackapps I succeeded. I converted it to a bitmap, reduced it with compress, and saved the stream directly. This success is thanks to you.